# Ubuntu theme on Gentoo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, themes, gentoo

I've just moved from Ubuntu 10.04 on Gentoo and wondering where I can get default Ubuntu gnome theme?

I would highly appreciate any interface customization howto's too.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually download, unpack and install the required files from [the relevant Ubuntu packages.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-artwork)

[`.deb` files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) really are archives in the [ar format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) with some companion metadata. File Roller should have no problem opening them.

Comment: The thing is that you can't simply download ubuntu-theme, because you need install gtk-engine related to this theme too and satisfy all it's dependencies.

Comment: @andrew -- I didn't suggest you to install the package. I suggested you to extract the contents and manually install the content. _Obviously_ they're GTK themes and if GTK is not what you're using, you'll need to convert them to whatever engine you need :)